# OP have changed the question that I have answered

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Please accept my apologies if this a duplicate question

But OP have changed the the original question that I have answered and have given a sorry in return

[How to get the ID to delete this item from the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536824/why-the-imagebutton-of-delete-operation-is-not-displayed-in-this-table)

What shall I do so OP can raise the changed question as a new question else OP will keep on changing this question again and again till project is complete

BTW I was advised on chat to raise a question on meta

Comment: ok, its been set to older version, check it again.

Comment: @Lucifer thank you very much please can you put this answer so I can accept it

Comment: if the user keeps it up, the question should be flagged as "Other" with an explanation of what is happening.

Comment: @HatSoft, it can't be an answer, however, you have already an detailed answer now.

Comment: nevermind my above in this case; I see from the comments the op already understands the mistake.

Comment: @OP did say his sorry which is very nice what I am trying to stop is OP's changing the same question again & again till project is complete

Comment: cheers guys very professional approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how much changed I either:

- add a comment to ask the OP to refrain from doing this in the future ("please ask a new question next time", in friendly, more verbose wording).
- Revert the edit, and ask the OP to create a new question, with a link to their original edit so they can retrieve their posting.

In the comment I specifically point out that people that answered do not get notified of the changes made to the question, and that editing a question to such an extent invalidates the existing answers and work put into them. This not only frustrates the original answerers, but also anyone visiting the question in the future, as the now out-of-date answers will be confusingly wrong for the current question.

If you cannot edit a question yourself yet, you can at least make a suggested edit, and comment accordingly.

If the OP shows a history of question switching, or persists in editing the one post to follow his evolving problem even after you gently guided him in the right direction, flag the post for moderator attention. Moderators have more tools to their disposal, but should only be called in for stubborn cases.

Comment: might want to add the info from my comment for cases where the op persists, which is nevertheless not the case here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Good idea, done.